# Initialising in-class member with constructor arguments with round ( ) brackets?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer

I'm sorry, I haven't programmed C++ in a while, I'd like to refresh my knowledge about what exact rule I'm violating here:

I can do:

```
int main()
{
    int a(5);
}
```

but cannot do:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a(5); // Error: expected a type specifier / Error: syntax error, 'constant'
}
```

I am trying to regain some lost knowledge, can someone direct me to the rule that disallows this? I'm pretty sure there'd be a question about it on here, I couldn't find it. The only thing I remember is that the committee debated (for C++11 I think) in class constructor arguments and introduced new squiggly bracket constructor initialisers, like int a{5}; but I would like to know why int a(5); isn't allowed inside a class. Has this always been disallowed in C++?

Comment: You can use assignment (`= 5`) or brace initializer (`{5}`)  syntax, what you tried never was possible.

Comment: `int a(5)` in class context is a declaration of function `a`, returning an `int` and with invalid argument `5`, that's what the error message is trying to say.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I thought about that, about the most vexing parse issue, but having a 5 constant int in the brackets makes it unambiguous, which is why it allows it in the main function, right? I'm just wondering if a rationale was given at all to help me remember. If not, that's OK.

Comment: Hmm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048163/c-most-vexing-parse-when-a-number-literal-is-the-argument

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for finding that. I assume that since πάντα ῥεῖ said declaring int a(5); in a class was NEVER possible in C++ that the title of that duplicate question is misleading in asking why in C++11. Also, the explanation in that question for why it would be disallowed is that: bar B(foo()); is ambiguous, in fact a function signature. But: int a(5) is not. I assume that's why you're allowed to write it in a function. I guess a reason hasn't been given other than that those are the rules. I'm not complaining, I don't expect everything to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A species of vexing parse. Names in default member initializers are supposed to be looked up in the completed class, because they are suppose to imitate constructor initializers. With `()`, the compiler won't be able to figure out what it's parsing, because it can refer to things declared later in the class:

```
struct X {
    int f(x); // function or data member?
    static const int x = 1;
};
```

Comment: "Names in default member initializers are supposed to be looked up in the completed class..." Thank you, that answers it for me. I was just about to let the issue go and take it for granted, this puts it in perspective for me, that the same line is parsed differently whether it's a class member or a declaration in a function, it seems. Thank you.

Comment: Umm, just one thing though, doesn't int f(5); not allow for any ambiguity because the constructor argument is a constant int literal? Just as in the main function?

Comment: `int f(5);` is unambiguous, but there's not much reason to only permit `()` in the unambiguous cases.

Comment: I see, except in functions it does allow it in unambiguous cases. Anyway, I don't want to draw this out unnecessarily, I guess it's just a rule disallowing this with class members. Thanks.